# regex in Ftp.parentFilter for excluding files doesnt work

Tags: java, regex, spring-boot, notifications, ftp

I need to create a regular expression for excluding files from FTP parentFilter() with extension .jpg
when I put such an expression ^.SIG$ or ^..SIG$ this doesnt work and even a symbol \ is not recognized by a spring boot. Can anybody help with such an expresiion?

"^.SIG$" or "^..SIG$"

Comment: ever tried something simple like: .filter(file -> !file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg") ?

Comment: Thank you a lot for a comment. But maybe there is some alternative for parentFiletr regex?

Comment: didn't I just provide you with an alternative?

Comment: Can we please get a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answear for my question. There is a possibility to create a bean like

```
@Bean
public GenericSelector<File> excludeJPG() {
    return new GenericSelector<File>() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File source) {
            return !source.getName().endsWith(".JPG");
        }
    };
}
```

and then pass it into a

```
IntegrationFlows
            .from(...)
            .filter(excludeJPG())
```